# How to bold a specific string in a sentence?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to bold the first string: myArray(c,3), but I don't know how to do. It shouldn't be difficult?

```
    For c = UBound(myArray) - LBound(myArray) + 1 To 1 Step -1
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("xxx").Range.InsertAfter myArray(c, 3) & myArray(c, 6)
        If c <> 1 Then ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("xxx").Range.InsertAfter vbNewLine
    Next c
```

I tried various options with Range.Characters().Bold = True, but it seems I can use only this notation Characters(5) and not Characters (2,5) in spite of what I have seen online. In other words, I will have to loop for each characters if I want them bold.

Is there a simple way to do it? Or something more efficient?

Answer (score 2):

A key point for you to note is this

> Also, if the range is a bookmark, Word inserts the specified text but
>   does not extend the range or the bookmark to include the new text.

From

[Help on InsertAfter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.insertafter?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm157155432)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Hence the following code wil, probably do what you want.

```
Public Sub testfmt()

    For c = UBound(myArray) - LBound(myArray) + 1 To 1 Step -1

        Dim myRange As Word.Range
        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("xxx").Range
        myRange.InsertAfter myArray(c, 3) & myArray(c, 6)
        myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        myRange.MoveEnd unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=len(myArray(c, 3))
        myRange.Font.Bold = True
        If c <> 1 Then ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("xxx").Range.InsertAfter vbNewLine

    Next c

End Sub
```

Update: After JLuc01's post I had a look using .select to test where the selection was after the insert after.

If I do

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("xxx").Range.InsertAfter "Hello" & "World"
```

The code works as expected

But in the case of

```
Dim myRange As Word.Range
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("xxx").Range
```

VBA no longer sees myRange as being a Bookmark range and consequently the range after the insert includes the bookmark and the inserted text.

Consequently the code should be revised to

```
Public Sub testfmt()

    For c = UBound(myArray) - LBound(myArray) + 1 To 1 Step -1

        Dim myRange As Word.Range
        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("xxx").Range
        myRange.InsertAfter myArray(c, 3) & myArray(c, 6)
        myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        myRange.Move unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-Len(myArray(c, 3) & myArray(c, 6))
        myRange.MoveEnd unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(myArray(c, 3))
        myRange.Font.Bold = True
        If c <> 1 Then ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("xxx").Range.InsertAfter vbNewLine

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: It is not working and I have difficulties to understand it. When I finished the for loop, I should have a new sentence, but this code is cutting my sentences and the bold appeared below where it should be. I tried to use MoveStart as I thought it will put the cursor to the right place, but no. I need to read more about Collapse and Move in the Microsoft help, because I am lost.

Comment: @JLuc01 As ever Word help is not as helpful as it might be.  I've added a new sub and an explanation of why the previous one didn't work.

Comment: Your revised code didn't work for me, but I found a solution which is working. I am using MoveStart instead of MoveEnd. I have to admit the coding is very difficult in VBA-Word, I don't really like the logic.

Comment: As long as you have a solution that's fine.  If you are complaining about Word's object model syntax then you'll be at the end of a very very long line.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to "freeflow", I could find a way to make it work.

```
 For c = UBound(myChemicalArray) - LBound(myChemicalArray) + 1 To 1 Step -1
        Dim myRange As Word.Range
        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("XXX").Range
        myRange.InsertAfter myArray(c, 3) & myArray(c, 6)
        myRange.MoveStart unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=7 ' For the key word used as Bookmark
        myRange.Font.Bold = True
        myRange.MoveStart unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(myArray(c, 3))
        myRange.Font.Bold = False
        If c <> 1 Then myRange.InsertAfter vbNewLine
Next c
```

Comment: Your solution uses a magic number (7) rather than values being derived from the object model.  My code will work irrespective of the length of myRange.